# Steps to capture IRQs in arm64 GICv3?

Tags: arm, arm64, bare-metal

I'm working on a bare-metal interrupt controller, GIC version 3. The underlying architecture is Virt, with QEMU, and a CPU Arm Cortex-72, aarch64:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,gic-version=3 -cpu cortex-a72 -nographic -kernel kernel.elf
```

According to the [ARMv8-A guide, Interrupt Group 1 Enable register](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0595/2020-12/AArch64-Registers/ICC-IGRPEN1-EL1--Interrupt-Controller-Interrupt-Group-1-Enable-register?lang=en), bit `0` of register `ICC_IGRPEN1_EL1` is the responsible for IRQs activation. This is an excerpt of it:

[image]

I specify that I work in NON SECURE mode.

I want to generate an IRQ from a timing context. The timer works well, but for any reason the IRQ is not captured even though bit `0`of `ICC_IGRPEN1_EL1` is set to 1.

Since I use several headers, I can't provide you a minimum example. I have no way, if you can suggest me how, please do it. However, I did the best possible to formulate a clear question, so I really hope you can help.

This is an excerpt of the function which shall generate the IRQ:

```
 void timer_init(void)
{
    uint64_t ticks, current_cnt;
 
    // Disable the timer
    disable_cntv();

    //read system frequency
    cntfrq = raw_read_cntfrq_el0();

    // Next timer IRQ is after 3 sec(s).
    ticks = 3 * cntfrq;
    
    // Get value of the current timer
    current_cnt = raw_read_cntvct_el0();
        
    // Set the interrupt in Current Time + TimerTick
    raw_write_cntv_cval_el0(current_cnt + ticks);

    // Enable the timer
    enable_cntv();

    // Enable IRQ   
    enable_irqs();
    
    while(1){
        wfi();  
    }
}
```

Function `enable_irqs` has been defined as follows:

```
void enable_irqs(void) {
    set_gic_gicc_igrpen1_el1(0x1);
}
```

In turn, function `set_gic_gicc_igrpen1_el1` is:

```
void set_gic_gicc_igrpen1_el1(uint64_t value)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__("msr s3_0_c12_c12_7 , %0" : : "r" (value));
}
```

I verified all the values with gdb: timer works and register `ICC_IGRPEN1_EL1` has the last bit which is set to `1`. Do you notice any errors in this code for which I do not receive any IRQs?

Not to be incomplete, the other functions I mentioned are implemented as follows:

```
void disable_cntv(void)
{
    uint32_t cntv_ctl;

    cntv_ctl = raw_read_cntv_ctl();
    cntv_ctl &= ~CNTV_CTL_ENABLE;
    __asm__ __volatile__("msr CNTV_CTL_EL0, %0\n\t" : : "r" (cntv_ctl) : "memory");
}

void enable_cntv(void)
{
    uint32_t cntv_ctl;

    cntv_ctl = raw_read_cntv_ctl();
    cntv_ctl |= CNTV_CTL_ENABLE;
    __asm__ __volatile__("msr CNTV_CTL_EL0, %0\n\t" : : "r" (cntv_ctl) : "memory");
}

uint32_t raw_read_cntfrq_el0(void)
{
    uint32_t cntfrq_el0;

    __asm__ __volatile__("mrs %0, CNTFRQ_EL0\n\t" : "=r" (cntfrq_el0) : : "memory");
    return cntfrq_el0;
}

void raw_write_cntv_cval_el0(uint64_t cntv_cval_el0)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__("msr CNTV_CVAL_EL0, %0\n\t" : : "r" (cntv_cval_el0) : "memory");
}

    uint64_t raw_read_cntvct_el0(void)
{
    uint64_t cntvct_el0;
        __asm__ __volatile__("mrs %0, CNTVCT_EL0\n\t" : "=r" (cntvct_el0) : : "memory");
        return cntvct_el0;
}

/* Wait For Interrupt */
#define wfi()       asm volatile("wfi" : : : "memory")
```

`CNTV_CTL_ENABLE` is defined as follows:

```
#define CNTV_CTL_ENABLE     (1 << 0)    /* Enables the timer */
```

Comment: I would suggest to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): some of your code is missing. i.e.`disable_cntv()`, `enable_cntv()`,...

Comment: Hello Frant, I don't know how to produce a minimum reproducible example.. I have several headers in my code, for instance the file with the initialization assembly, the one that capture the exceptions, etc.. Several files that are all necessary to reproduce something. :/ For instance, I didn't provide functions timer-related because I verified that the timer works properly...

Comment: A single, minimal C file would do - just copy/paste what you are really using into it. No non-standard includes, no  need for startup code nor for the linker script.

Comment: Ok! I update the question, I hope that it is better, even though it is not reproducible without the "complete" infrastructure :)

Comment: I may have missed it, but I don't see where you are enabling `PPI_11_IRQn`,  `PPI_13_IRQn` or  `PPI_14_IRQn` in the `GICv3`. With a `GICv2`, you would write the interrupt number you want to enable with something like: `GICDistributor->ISENABLER[IRQn / 32U] = 1U << (IRQn % 32U);`

Comment: Dear Frant, in GICv2 I am able to receive a IRQ by enabling the DAIF register: `__asm__ __volatile__("msr DAIFClr, %0\n\t" : : "i" (DAIF_IRQ_BIT)  : "memory");`, where `DAIF_IRQ_BIT` is defined as `(1<<1)`. This is completely useless in GICv3 as long as I can notice. But, I did not know that I had to set such PPIs registers. Do you have some details more or a little example, please?

Comment: See section `4.3SPI, PPI and SGI configuration` of [GICv3 and GICv4 Software Overview Release B](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5f1068720daa596235e7f6ef?token=): the step `Enable(GICD_ISENABLERn, GICD_ICENABLER, GICR_ISENABLER0, GICR_ICENABLER0)` may be missing: You need to enable the interrupt in both the Architectural Timer AND the GICv3.